# is not going to deleted by python interpreter about key and value in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, relation

i'm not good at english and i'm noob at python but i have tiny question about python map

are they assigned relation each key and value?
if i created some object like this

```
my_map = {}
my_map['id'] = someObject()
```

is someObject not Dangling Pointer?
is not gonna delete by python interpreter?

Comment: No, it is not a dangling pointer because it is an item in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Formally:

`my_map['id']` is a [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions)

then you have:

> Assignment statements are used to (re)bind names to values and to
>   modify attributes or items of mutable objects:
>
> ...
>
> If the primary is a mapping object (such as a dictionary), the
>   subscript must have a type compatible with the mapping’s key type, and
>   **the mapping is then asked to create a key/datum pair which maps the
>   *subscript* to the assigned object**. This can either replace an existing
>   key/value pair with the same key value, or insert a new key/value pair
>   (if no key with the same value existed).

from here [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

So basically you are binding/mapping the recently created object to the *subscript* and of course, the newly created object can be referenced by `my_map['id']` so the Python garbage collector can't touch it (reclaim it) and it is not a "dangling pointer" or to be more precise an object without any reference to it.

Side note: a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) is not a term used to refer to an object without reference (how appears you were using the term) but to a reference to a nonvalid object (and this is impossible in Python).

Answer (score 0):

There is no pointer in Python. There is name bound to object in Python.